# Spark SQL DataFrame join with filter is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter df1 by joining df2 based on some column and then filter some rows from df1 based on filter.

**df1:**

```
+---------------+----------+
|        channel|rag_status|
+---------------+----------+
|            STS|     green|
|Rapid Cash Plus|     green|
|        DOTOPAL|     green|
|     RAPID CASH|     green|
```

**df2:**

```
+---------------+----------+
|        channel|rag_status|
+---------------+----------+
|            STS|      blue|
|Rapid Cash Plus|      blue|
|        DOTOPAL|      blue|
+---------------+----------+
```

**Sample code is:**

```
df1.join(df2, df1.col("channel") === df2.col("channel"), "leftouter")
      .filter(not(df1.col("rag_status") === "green"))
      .select(df1.col("channel"), df1.col("rag_status")).show
```

Its not returning any records.

I'm expecting the output as below one, which is returned from df1 after filtering the records based on `channel` and `green` status condition. If the same channel is available in the df2 and the df1 `rag_status` is green, then remove that record from df1 and return the remaining records only from df1.

**Expected output is:**

```
+---------------+----------+
|        channel|rag_status|
+---------------+----------+
|     RAPID CASH|     green|
```

Comment: You don't have any `rag_status` other than green in your first dataframe, so the filter `filter(not(df1.col("rag_status") === "green"))` works as expected because you ask for the rows where `rag_status` is NOT green in `df1`, and there are none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work something like this :

```
val df1=sc.parallelize(Seq(("STS","green"),("Rapid Cash Plus","green"),("RAPID CASH","green"))).toDF("channel","rag_status").where($"rag_status"==="green")
val df2=sc.parallelize(Seq(("STS","blue"),("Rapid Cash Plus","blue"),("DOTOPAL","blue"))).toDF("channel","rag_status").withColumnRenamed("rag_status","rag_status2")
val leftJoinResult=df1.join(df2,Array("channel"),"left")
val innerJoinResult=df1.join(df2,"channel")
val resultDF=leftJoinResult.except(innerJoinResult).drop("rag_status2")
resultDF.show
```

**Spark-shell Output:**

```
scala> val df1=sc.parallelize(Seq(("STS","green"),("Rapid Cash Plus","green"),("RAPID CASH","green"))).toDF("channel","rag_status").where($"rag_status"==="green")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [channel: string, rag_status: string]

scala> val df2=sc.parallelize(Seq(("STS","blue"),("Rapid Cash Plus","blue"),("DOTOPAL","blue"))).toDF("channel","rag_status").withColumnRenamed("rag_status","rag_status2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [channel: string, rag_status2: string]

scala> val leftJoinResult=df1.join(df2,Array("channel"),"left")
leftJoinResult: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [channel: string, rag_status: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val innerJoinResult=df1.join(df2,"channel")
innerJoinResult: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [channel: string, rag_status: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val resultDF=leftJoinResult.except(innerJoinResult).drop("rag_status2")
resultDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [channel: string, rag_status: string]

scala> resultDF.show
+----------+----------+                                                         
|   channel|rag_status|
+----------+----------+
|RAPID CASH|     green|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: your code is not working, if i remove DOTOPAL from df1.. i will edit my question to make it very simple..

Comment: As you have fully changed the question ! hence answer is completely updated !

Comment: the output contains two rag_status, where one rag_status is coming as null, so when i try to take rag_status it says, column is ambiguous

Comment: See i have renamed the column !

Comment: @Shankar : Good to know  :) Accept it then :P

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to get expected output:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("channel"), "leftouter").filter(row => row(3) != "blue")
```